# scan a sequence of lines of strings with white spaces

Tags: c

My code is for reading an input of strings and newline is used as delimiter. But my code doesn't read the inputs correctly and the output is different from the input. In my code i used %*[\n]c to read the newline character for if any present and skip it so that it is not included while reading the next string.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  main()
  {
     char s[100],s1[100],s2[100];
     scanf("%[^\n]s%*[\n]c%[^\n]s%*[\n]c%[^\n]s%*[\n]c",s,s1,s2);
     printf("%s%s%s",s,s1,s2);
     return 0;
  }
```

My inputs for this program are below:

```
this is 1st line
this is 2nd line
this is 3rd line
```

My output is

```
this is 1st line.N=ö
```

Can someone correct my code.Thank you.

Comment: `scanf(" %99[^\n] %99[^\n] %99[^\n]", s, s1, s2);`

Comment: 1. Learn about other file IO functions beside scanf. 2. Get a modern C book, the one you are using is teaching you ancient coding style (write `int main (void)` ).

Comment: How does a file IO is useful for my code as they are useful only for file and my code is not written for file?

Comment: @reswanth-- everything is a file. Use `fgets()` to get a line of input from a file stream, which may be `stdin`. Then use `sscanf()` on the string obtained; this has many advantages over using `scanf()` to scan values from the user as they are entered.

Answer (score 1):

In the posted code, there is a risk of buffer overflow since no maximum width is specified for the input buffers. Such widths should always be specified for safe code; remember to leave space for the null character that terminates the string.

```
scanf(" %99[^\n] %99[^\n] %99[^\n]", s, s1, s2);
```

The `fgets()` function is better suited to read lines of input. Note that `fgets()` keeps the newline when it reads a line of input, so you may want to remove this in some cases. Also, if the user inputs more characters than will fit in the specified buffer, the newline and some characters will remain in the input stream. But this is no different than using `scanf()`, in that one must always be careful about what may be left behind in the input stream after an IO operation. In any event, using `fgets()` is generally less error-prone than using `scanf()`, and there is benefit in having user input stored in a string. The `sscanf()` function can always be used on the string obtained with `fgets()`, but in this case you still have the input string to work with after calling `sscanf()`.

Also, note that the function signature in the OP code needs to be one of:

```
int main(void)

int main(int argc, char **argv)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Here is an example using `fgets()` to read and then display lines of input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINES  25
#define BUF_LEN   1000

int main(void)
{
    char lines[MAXLINES][BUF_LEN];
    size_t num_lines = 0;

    puts("Enter some lines of text (empty line to quit):");

    for(num_lines = 0; num_lines < MAXLINES; num_lines++) {
        if (fgets(lines[num_lines], BUF_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (lines[num_lines][0] == '\n') {
                break;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
        printf("%s",lines[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char s[100], s1[100], s2[100];
    scanf("%[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n]", s, s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", s, s1, s2);
}
```

Comment: Every answer here should contain an explanation. Also, you forgot to specify the return type of `main`. And your code can lead to buffer overflows.